# Win32 Application LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, linker, static-linking

I have been trying to make a WIN32 Application with a GUI (NOT a simple console application) on VS2012, and I'm stuck with this one error. My project is on Release configuration. My main function looks like this:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), NULL, DlgProc);
}
```

What I've tried:

1) Creating a new WIN32 Project with these settings:

- Application Type -> Windows application
- Additional options -> Empty Project (With NO SDL!)
- No other options checked

2) Changing between Unicode and Multi-Byte Character Sets

3) Changing the SubSystem (from Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) to Not Set)

4) Adding entry points (main ; _main ; WinMain)

5) Adding #undef _ATL_MIN_CRT (I'm pretty sure it was disabled anyway, but still did it for extra insurance...)

NONE of these solved my issue. I've searched the Internet and haven't found anyone with a similar problem (creating a WIN32 Application) who has solved their issue.

**EDIT**: I'm also using Allegro 5 library and I'm building the program with /MT .

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: I think WinMain might be just for GUI apps, not console...

Comment: I wasn't trying to make a console app...

Comment: so you're trying to use some pre existing code and "fit it into" a new VS project, is that right?

Comment: @rogerdpack `WinMain` is just a name. The signature posted above is the signature for any Windows executable. There is no such thing as a GUI app or Console app in Windows anyway. It's an executable.

Comment: When compiling this exact code (with an #include <Windows.h>) it runs fine when I execute your first step and add it in a main.cpp file. Is there any other code you use? And where did you add this function?

Comment: When you say that you want to build a WIN32 application, not a Win32 console, you seem to be under the impression, that a console application is somehow not a Win32 application. You need to clarify what you really want.

Comment: @IInspectable I want to make a WIN32 Application with a GUI

Comment: I think You misunderstood me...

Comment: It seems that you are flailing around with little clear understanding. You appear to be changing every setting that you can think of. You state that you have set `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. In which case why is the compiler looking for `_main`. The symptoms that you describe are not consistent with your stated *facts*. Please try and clear this up.

Comment: @David Heffernan   I just tested it and it's really looking for `_main` even though `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is set. I guess Allegro 5 has something to do with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I've found the answer.

All I needed to do was to define ALLEGRO_NO_MAGIC_MAIN .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the wrong calling convention for your `main` function. As the documentation for [Name Decoration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx) explains, a symbol with a leading underscore and no other decorations indicates *C calling convention*.

The signature for your `main` function should be:

```
extern "C" __cdecl void main();
```

Note that neither the return value nor the argument list are part of the name decoration, since the caller is responsible for cleanup. This means that any function signature can be used to satisfy the linker.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't Visual Studio see that I'm making a WIN32 Application and replace my [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms633559.aspx) with the appropriate form?

Comment: Visual Studio is a tool that does what you tell it to. If you want `WinMain` to be your entry point you should set `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` and provide your entry point of choice to the linker settings.

Comment: If that is the case, the CRT should not try to call `main`, but rather `WinMain`. Remove Allegro 5 to solve the problem in isolation.